# how to send javascript array to database using php

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, database

I have an array of strings in javascript, I want to send it to a database using PHP. I have been searching everywhere trying to convert the array to PHP array and then send it. I am already connected to the database just need to send this array.

Comment: Could you add which database are you using? And how are you connecting to the this database from pHp. That would give us some more context rather than this being an open-ended discussion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about client-side Javascript (JS) and not something like NodeJS, you can't just convert a JS array into a PHP array, since the PHP array lives on the server side. So, what you can do, is send it to the server. You can either do this through a standard POST request, or, what I'm assuming would be the better option for you, through an Asycronous (AJAX) request.

There are several tutorials on how to use AJAX, and depending on any existing libraries that you already have in place, you may choose to follow a jQuery or Angular specific one. 
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ajax/index.htm

Once you send it to the server, you're likely reading it from the PHP `$_POST` array. Then you would acccess the posted array (sanitize/validate it, because we NEVER trust data from the client) and then you can save that data to the database that you've already setup the connection for.